# Python - define function using decision statement and return variable

Tags: python, function, if-statement, methods, user-defined-functions

I am a newbie in Python, and I am writing a program that involves defining my own function that determines if a customer receives a discount on their ticket. First I ask if they preregistered, then call my function that has an if-then-else decision statement, it either applies a 10% discount or does not. I am uncertain as to what I am doing wrong with my program, any suggestions? 
Edit: my output returns 0$ right now, and I'm hoping to have it either outpu 20$ if not preregistered or calculate 10% off of 20$ if preregistered.

```
def determineDiscount(register, cost):
#Test if the user gets a discount here. Display a message to the screen either way.
    if register == "YES":
        cost = cost * 0.9
        print("You are preregistered and qualify for a 10% discount.")
    else:
        print("Sorry, you did not preregister and do not qualify for a 10% discount.")
    return cost

#Declarations
registered = ''
cost = 0
ticketCost = 20 

registered = input("Have you preregistered for the art show?")
determineDiscount(registered, ticketCost)

print("Your final ticket price is", cost, "$")
```

Comment: What is your question? Your indentation is off, so fix it to reflect the code you are actually running. You need to articulate a problem statement, such as "when I run such and such, I get such and such error, here is the full trace-back..." Assuming your indentation is correct, I notice immediately that you aren't capturing the value returned by your function. So `cost` will always be `0`

Comment: One more thing, which python you use. In 2.7 there is no input(), in python3 it is.
Eventually convert all input to upper case. Now if you enter "YES" then you have discount, if you type "yes", then you don't have it.

Comment: Please specify your question. If it does not run, please provide the error stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should use `raw_input` in PY2 and `input` in PY3.
Also the cost returned by the function must be stored in cost, otherwise it'll remain unchanged. cost outside the function is not the same than cost inside the function.

```
def determineDiscount(register, cost):
    if register.lower() == "yes":
        cost *= 0.9
        print("You are preregistered and qualify for a 10% discount.")
    else:
        print("Sorry, you did not preregister and do not qualify for a 10% discount.")
    return cost


ticketCost = 20
registered = raw_input("Have you preregistered for the art show?")
cost = determineDiscount(registered, ticketCost)

print("Your final ticket price is", cost, "$")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def determineDiscount(register, cost):
#Test if the user gets a discount here. Display a message to the screen either way.
    if register.lower() == "yes": #make user's input lower to avoid problems
        cost -= cost * 0.10 #formula for the discount
        print("You are preregistered and qualify for a 10% discount.")
    else:
        print("Sorry, you did not preregister and do not qualify for a 10% discount.")
    return cost
#Declarations
ticketCost = 20
#get user input
registered = input("Have you preregistered for the art show?")
#call function in your print()
print("Your final ticket price is $", determineDiscount(registered, ticketCost))
```

Output:

```
Have you preregistered for the art show?yes
You are preregistered and qualify for a 10% discount.
Your final ticket price is $18
```